# Airflow unpause dag programmatically?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a dag that we'll deploy to multiple different airflow instances and in our airflow.cfg we have `dags_are_paused_at_creation = True` but for this specific dag we want it to be turned on without having to do so manually by clicking on the UI. Is there a way to do it programmatically?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

airflow-rest-api-plugin plugin can also be used to programmatically pause tasks.

> Pauses a DAG
>
> Available in Airflow Version: 1.7.0 or greater
>
> GET - http://{HOST}:{PORT}/admin/rest_api/api?api=pause
>
> Query Arguments:
>
> dag_id - string - The id of the dag
>
> subdir (optional) - string - File location or directory from which to
>   look for the dag
>
> Examples:
>
> http://{HOST}:{PORT}/admin/rest_api/api?api=pause&dag_id=test_id

See for more details: 
https://github.com/teamclairvoyant/airflow-rest-api-plugin

Answer (score 29):

I created the following function to do so if anyone else runs into this issue:

```
import airflow.settings
from airflow.models import DagModel
def unpause_dag(dag):
    """
    A way to programatically unpause a DAG.
    :param dag: DAG object
    :return: dag.is_paused is now False
    """
    session = airflow.settings.Session()
    try:
        qry = session.query(DagModel).filter(DagModel.dag_id == dag.dag_id)
        d = qry.first()
        d.is_paused = False
        session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
    finally:
        session.close()
```

Comment: you could also use unpause(args='', dag=dag) method in airflow.bin.cli

Answer (score 9):

supply your dag_id and run this command on your command line.

```
airflow pause dag_id.
```

For more information on the airflow command line interface: https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/cli.html

Comment: Awesome, can't believe I missed this. Not exactly programmatically but nonetheless can just use a BashOperator to run that or use the subcommand module to execute it. I also see now here https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/bin/cli.py#L307 that I have the same code so yeah I will just use this.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for `unpause` ( not `pause`)

```
airflow unpause DAG_ID
```

Answer (score 2):

The following cli command should work per the recent docs.

```
airflow dags unpause dag_id
```

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#unpause

Answer (score 1):

Airflow's REST API provides a way using the DAG patch API: we need to update the dag with query parameter `?update_mask=is_paused` and send boolean as request body.

Ref: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/patch_dag

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using in the python operator of any dag to pause and unpause the dags programatically . This is the best approch i found instead of using cli just pass the list of dags and rest is take care

```
from airflow.models import DagModel
dag_id = "dag_name"
dag = DagModel.get_dagmodel(dag_id)
dag.set_is_paused(is_paused=False)
```

And just if you want to check if it is paused or not it will return boolean

```
dag.is_paused()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
airflow pause dag_id.
```

has been discontinued.

You will have to use:

```
airflow dags pause dag_id
```

Answer (score 0):

a bash approach of srinivasreddyramaram comment could be this one, please notice that you need predefined variables like `$DEFAULT_PASSWORD`, `$ENDPOINT_URL`, and `Dag id`.

The default password belongs to the password used in the Airflow UI, the endpoint URL, is the URL to access your UI, and finally, the dag id is self-explanatory.

A possible approach to implement these rest API calls could be a bootstrap dag, that updates the airflow-providers-amazon library from version 6.0.0 to 6.1.0, because you need to assume some role arn.

```
restApiResponse=$(curl \
        -s \
        --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
        --request PATCH \
        --user "admin:$DEFAULT_PASSWORD" \
        -w "%{stdout}" \
        --data '{"is_paused": false}' \
        "${ENDPOINT_URL}/api/v1/dags/$DagId?update_mask=is_paused")

echo $restApiResponse
```