# How to pause / Un pause multiple dags in airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

We have 100 of dags which has a prefix with "dag_EDW_HC_*" . we have below command to pause the dag

```
Command: airflow pause dag_id
```

Is there any way we can pause all the 100 dags "dag_EDW_HC_*"  in a single go .. (In programmatic in python or any other way) ..?

Comment: I also referred few of the links like   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44360354/airflow-unpause-dag-programmatically but to pause multiple dags i havent got any reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The absolute easiest (*and likely fastest*) way I can think of is to update the database:

```sql
UPDATE  dag
   SET  is_paused = false
 WHERE  dag_id LIKE 'dag_EDW_HC%';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply.. So iit means , in airflow database directory inside DAG table , we can make it as false ?

Comment: what happens if DAGs are currently running and we carry out this update ?

Comment: The same thing that would happen if you did it through any other means: new tasks/runs won't be scheduled.

Comment: Since Feb 2022, Google provides a composer_dags.py script to do this. Check my answer below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/74026479/391034) on how to use it

Comment: Hi @joebeeson - I don't have permission to directly update composer database , how can I update dag table programmatically ? - Santanu

Comment: @SantanuGhosh if you have terminal access I'd look into `xargs` and the `airflow pause` command and do the action there.

Answer (score 1):

The following BashOperators list all DAGs but your could either repeat each or or 'grep' to your liking:

```
BashOperator(task_id="pause_dags",
    bash_command="airflow dags list -o plain | grep -o '^\S*' | xargs -L1 -t airflow dags pause"
)
```

```
BashOperator(task_id="unpause_dags",
    bash_command="airflow dags list -o plain | grep -o '^\S*' | xargs -L1 -t airflow dags unpause"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this regularly you can create a DAG specifically for this purpose with the corresponding `PythonOperator` for that and specify parameters when triggering DAG.
From a running task instance (in the `python_callable` function that we pass to a `PythonOperator` or in the `execute` method of a custom operator) you have access to the `DagBag` object which contains dag ids of all DAGs loaded into Airflow environment which you can use to get `DagModel`-s which you can loop through and pause all DAGs:

```
def python_callable():
   dag_bag = DagBag(read_dags_from_db=False)
   for dag_id_ in dag_bag.dag_ids:
       dag_model = airflow.models.dag.DagModel.get_dagmodel(dag_id_)
       dag_model.set_is_paused(True)
```

The current code is for the `2.0.1` version and it could differ for different versions of Airflow. You should check the documentation for your version of Airflow server if this callable does not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since Feb 2022, Google provides a `composer_dags.py` script which can be used to pause all your DAGs in a given environment, using the below command:

```
python3 composer_dags.py --environment COMPOSER_1_ENV \
  --project PROJECT_ID \
  --location COMPOSER_1_LOCATION \
  --operation pause
```

source: https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/migrate-composer-2-snapshots-af-1#step_pause_dags_in_your_environment