# Add tags in DAG

Tags: python, bash, continuous-integration, airflow

I have a question about updating python DAG files for Airflow.
I have almost 2000 DAG files, and I want to manage versioning on my CI/CD pipeline.

What I want to achieve is to update physically the python file on my CI to add a tag to my DAG like `tags=['version:v1.0.0']` before sending it to airflow.

DAGs came from different developers so the DAG definition il not always the same, I've identified multiple ways of declarations, here are some examples :

- Implicit dag_id:

  ```py
  dag = DAG(
      'mydummydag',
      default_args=default_args,
      description='mydescription',
      schedule_interval=None,
      dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=20))
  ```
- Explicit dag_id :

  ```py
  dag = DAG(
      dag_id='mydummydag',
      default_args=default_args,
      description='mydescription',
      schedule_interval=None,
      dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=20))
  ```
- Some tag are already present, but not version :

  ```py
  dag = DAG(
          dag_id='mydummydag',
          default_args=default_args,
          description='mydescription',
          schedule_interval=None,
          tags=['mytag1','mytag2'],
          dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=20))
  ```

- Version tag is already present, we need to update it :

  ```py
   dag = DAG(
      dag_id='mydummydag',
      default_args=default_args,
      description='mydescription',
      schedule_interval=None,
      tags=['version:1.0.0','mytag2'],
          dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=20))
  ```

The content of the DAG classe can be completely random on the order of the parameters and the usage of them (as soon as they exist in the class definition).

The process to update the version number is already working as I already update a VERSION file in my repo.
My question is just about the python DAG files, if someone has an idea how to do this.

It should be done in bash or python but I'm not closed.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake but dag_is = dag_id :) fat fingers you know ? :D

Comment: Please note you can [edit] your questions.

Comment: I'm not really clear into what is the question here.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe.

Comment: @Elad My question is How to open the python file, add the tag version in my DAG definition and save this.

I was thinking to use some regex + sed commands to achieve this but as the DAG definition can be completely random, I was searching for some advice to achieve this

Comment: @Guillaume I don't think this is an Airflow question. You are asking here how from CI you can add a commit to the PR in order to add/modify the code line for adding the tag.

Comment: No I know how to commit from the CI, I know how to update the version, I know how to open, edit and close the file but I don't know how to edit the DAG class In the ci, how to add the string `tags=['version:1.0.0']` at the good place and update it if already present with or without other tags. I don't know if I'm clear (You're true it's not an Airflow question, Airflow is for giving some context of my usage)

Comment: @Guillaume Do you know how to do it for any other python file? what is the difference? Airflow DAG file is like any other python file.

Comment: @Guillaume By the way check [AIP-36](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/AIP-36+DAG+Versioning) which will add DAG Versioning abilities. You are welcome to share your thoughts on the AIP page.

Comment: @Elad forget about airflow, I have a python script and I want to update the DAG object definition programmatically, is this more clear ?

Comment: @Guillaume the DAG entry in the database is being constantly updated from the dag file. I think you are looking for something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44360354/airflow-unpause-dag-programmatically but this will not work for tags. You need to do a text edit to the `.py` file of the DAG find the row of the tag in the code and replace it with whatever logic you wish. After you will change the dag code in the `.py` file it will be updated in the metastore db and the tags will be added. Is this more helpful?

Comment: Yes I have all this process ready, I just left the 'whatever logic you wish', I started something with some regex and sed in bash but the result was not very robust as the DAG declaration in the `.py` file is not always the same (like the example in the first question)

Comment: @Guillaume how do you handle a case of dynamically created DAGs? this is not listed in the options on your post.

Comment: @elad it's not an option, my input is a python file (with a DAG definition) and my output is just to add the tag "version" to this file with the 'whatever logic' so I need help for that 'whatever logic'